# Accessing phpmyadmin in specific Port

Tags: phpmyadmin, port

I am recently got a credential to migrate a website to a new server environment. 
but there is a problem on accessing a phpmyadmin from our server which specified with port 8081. The url for the phpmyadmin is something like : web.outboundomain.com:8081/phpmyadmin 
I couldn't access the url, there is a chance that the port is not listed as a safe port on my network. Is there any solution for me to allow my network accessing the url with specific port? 
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has solved. The main problem was my network / firewall blocked certain port. By asking it to release the block for port 8081 to the network administrator. Everything is solved. The problem might be vary but checking out blocked port would be good for the first approach